# Thread safe collection in Scala for Akka Actors

Tags: scala, list, akka

I am relatively new in Scala and struggling with deciding best way to have a thread safe collection.

I have an actor which is responsible for registering / un-registering orders. I was able to achieve it by

```
 class OrderOperationActor(orders: ListBuffer[Order]) extends Actor{
override def receive = {
case incomingOrder: IncomingOrder => {
   if(incomingOrder.orderOperation == OrderOperation.Register){
      println("Registering a new order in the list ")
      orders += incomingOrder.order
      sender ! orders
   }
  else{
     println("Un-registering a new order in the list ")
     orders -= incomingOrder.order
     sender ! orders
   }
}
 }
}
```

but wondering if is it a best choice , as for removing the items time complexity would be high ? Could we have used map instead?

Comment: There's no need to use a thread-safe collection in an actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutable collections. That makes a `ListBuffer` an absolute no-go! Actually, aim for immutability in general (absolutely while passing messages between of actors or your implementation will be broken). You will have to explicitly import them from `scala.collection.immutable` package. On the other hand, I can't see a reason why would you pass a collection of orders instead of declaring it as a `var` within of an actor.

Comment: So yo're saying to make operation thread safe , we should aim for immutability , but is it good idea to create a new list every time when we can have simply added or removed?

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea? There are some cases when mutable objects can be slightly more performant, but I don't see a reason not to use immutable collections.